# msvcr90d.dll not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have been working in a project that have been working wothount problems till today. Suddenly I have an error that "msvcp90d.dll not found" and program don't run into VS2008. In the last time the only dependency I have added is ftgl font rendering, but it has no sense.

What could be the casue of the problem?

Update: I think that my problem is another. When I clean and rebuild, the error message is "msvcr90d.dll not found". Some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msvcp90d is c++ stl library debug version. it is used automatically when you use standard c++ libraries.

Since this is debug library it is not supposed to be used in production environments. Possible reason why it is missing on computer where Visual Studio is installed is that you don't have debug libraries installed that computer. Use Visual Studio installation DVD and check it.

**update:** You can also setup your project to work without that dll file. Go to Project properties, then open Configuration properties - C/C++ - Code Generation tab. Set Runtime Library option to something without DLL in its name. (There are two versions: Release and Debug, use the one corresponding to your project'c configuration.)

Comment: I don't think it is the problem. The project has been compiled and executed in the same machine with the same VS2008, using STL and always was correctly compiled and executed under Visual studio. It is now that don't execute

Comment: You can also make it work without that dll file. See the update in my answer.